# Hide icon if author meta data doesn't exist

Tags: php, css, wordpress, elementor

I have created author pages using Elementor and am displaying icons that link to the author's social media pages. If there are no social media links stored against the author, I would like to hide the relevant icons.

In other words, if the author metadata `facebook_handle` does not exist, I would like to hide the `facebook_icon`

I have used the below code, but it seems to have hidden the icon regardless of whether the metadata exists or not. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
// Hide Facebook icon if no facebook_handle

    function facebook_icon_display(){
    
    $facebook = get_the_author_meta('facebook_handle', true);

    if(empty($facebook)) : ?>
        <style type="text/css">
                    #facebook_icon   {
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>;
        <?php endif; 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'facebook_icon_display', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: did you echo the `$facebook` and see what you got?

Comment: Hi Bhautik. Thanks for the response. I have tried echo with `$facebook`, as well as `if(empty($facebook))` and neither seem to be picking up the actual author metadata. Which is confusing, because I've created a shortcode using `get_the_author_meta('facebook_handle')` on other parts of my site.

Comment: Is the author defined in this function?

Comment: Hi Howard. Ah, that may be the issue - would I need to define the author based on the post I am viewing?  Any suggestions on how to go about doing so?

Comment: Use `global $post;` at the start of your function, and see if that is already filled at this point. If not, you might need to go via `get_queried_object` instead. Then get the `post_author` from that post, and pass it into `get_the_author_meta` as second parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help and guidance.
The working code is:
`

```
function facebook_icon_display(){
    
    global $post;
    $author_id=$post->post_author;

    $facebook = get_the_author_meta('facebook_handle', $author_id);
    
    if(empty($facebook)) : ?>
        <style type="text/css">
                    #facebook_icon   {
                        display: none;
                    }
                </style>;
        <?php endif; 
    }
    add_action( 'wp_head', 'facebook_icon_display', 10, 1 );`
```